# Help Importing an Excel File into MySQL using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, excel, phpmyadmin, rounding

I am uploading Excel files (.xls) containing numeric values such as 884.557 and 731.0547 into a MySQL database using phpMyAdmin's built-in Import function. However, I am having horrible rounding/truncation issues. For some reason, some values like 884.557 and 731.0547 are changed to 99.99999 or 9.99999. However, other values like 127.0947 are imported correctly. Can anyone help? If possible, I would still like to use the built-in phpMyAdmin Import function because it is useful.

Comment: have you tried to change the "." to "," for the decimal place? Maybe it is a localization error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with html and php, by using this script [simplex excel library](https://web.archive.org/web/20121105204536/http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/simple-xlsx/simplexlsx.class.php) you can create your own excel import to mysql. It may take few minutes to create but once your create you can use it for life time.

CREATE A HTML FORM TO UPLOAD EXCEL SHEET

THEN CREATE A PHP SCRIPT LIKE BELOW

```
require 'simplexlsx.class.php';

if (isset($_FILES['Filedata'])) {

$file = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']; // UPLOADED EXCEL FILE

$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX($file);

list($cols, $rows) = $xlsx->dimension();

foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) { // LOOP THROUGH EXCEL WORKSHEET

$q = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME(COL1, COL2) VALUE(";
      $q .=  "'".mysql_escape_string($r[0])."', "; // EXCEL DATA
      $q .=  "'".mysql_escape_string($r[1])."', "; // EXCEL DATA
      $q .= ")";

      $sql = mysql_query($q);

        } // IF ENDS HERE
        } // FOR EACH LOOP
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i normally do:

1. Save the excel file as CSV format
2. I will manually create the database table by indicating the data-types for every column of my interest.
3. I will upload the csv file to the selected table by ignoring the "column names" as i have defined it at step 2. Decimals are truncated because phpmyadmin has some unexplained algorithm to determine the data type and the size allocated to a column. To prevent that, you create the table as mentioned above at step 2.

Hope it helps!