# Data Excel to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel

I have a Excel File that contain lot of data Like District , Assembly Constituency and Locality.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ju45ibd913e8j3n/DilliVotes-Election-Data-Locality.xlsx

I want to store these data in database MySQL. I want District add in District Table, Assembly Constituency add in Assembly Constituency table as well as with district id.

Please help Me.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330242/how-to-import-excel-file-into-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin

Comment: Read Excel file (using a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)), iterate over each row reading cell values, insert values into database, repeat until end of file

Comment: or save as > csv, then import, should make it esier

Comment: http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/export/

Comment: thanks all to support me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export XLS to CSV and import the CSV to an existing table.